# angular.copy on element of type CSSStyleDeclaration

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

ran into a problem using angularjs writing:

```
const originalStyles = angular.copy(el.style)
```

when style is of type:

```
CSSStyleDeclaration
```

later on,i try to access originalStyles.position
it works well on chrome, but fails on safari throwing the error

> TypeError: The CSSStyleDeclaration.position getter can only be used on
> instances of CSSStyleDeclaration

can you please explain why it fails?